# Is there a way to check the health endpoint status is DOWN in local environment

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using java 1.8 and spring-boot-starter-parent 1.5.6.RELEASE. I have started my server using the following command,

```
java -jar my-application.jar
```

health endpoint status returns "UP" properly. I want to check the status is "DOWN".

```
localhost:8080/health
```

How do I check the status: DOWN in my local environment??

Comment: One question - why? Sounds like you are trying to test the frameworks code rather than trust it.

Comment: No, not like that, but I want to know which scenario it fails and returns the status  as DOWN.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-health and is based on these autoconfigured health indicators.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#_auto_configured_healthindicators